# How to disable all exception to enable phalcons debugging?

Tags: debugging, phalcon

I want to use the internal debugging component from phalcon:

http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/debug.html#debug-component

```
<?php

$debug = new \Phalcon\Debug();
$debug->listen();
```

It is written there that:

> *Any Try/Catch blocks must be removed or disabled to make this component work properly.*

so far so good, but how do i disable globally all exceptions in a project. For now i did not find any solution, perhaps there is a possibility to configure phalcon or the debug component.

Some ideas? Even wehn you tell me that you not using the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a trivial problem when we attempt to achieve a centralized exception handling in an application.

You should define your app's exception types and make them to come from the same base class. Just like all PHP exceptions comes from `Exception` and Phalcon exceptions comes from `Phalcon\Exception` you should have your own Exception base class so you're able to change their behavior at once and more importantly don't replicate loads of try/catch statements all over your code.

If that project already have try/catch statements everywhere, I'd recommend you to refactor your exceptions. If decide to do so, take a look on [**this library**](http://phalconist.com/8708394-whoops). It's very easy to use and supports Phalcon.

---

#### EDIT

Yes, I've got that you're trying to disable your exceptions (throw them directly to Phalcon\Debug right?) and not to centralize their handling. But by sub-classing all my exceptions I can control their behavior at once. In the application I'm working on, for example, I've put a breakpoint in the constructor of the base exception since it's [**much more useful**](http://www.phptherightway.com/#xdebug) than a pretty exception message. Here's how it looks like so far:

```
<?php
namespace MyApp\Exceptions;

use Exception as RawException;
use LogicException;
use Phalcon\Exception as PhException;

abstract class ExceptionBase extends PhException
{
    const CODE_UNKNOWN = 1;

    /** @var bool Set it to true to see what is going on before the server explodes */
    public static $holdYourHorses = false;

    /** @var bool Internal flag used to assert that constructor chain was called correctly */
    private $baseConstructorCalled = false;

    /**
     * Base constructor for all managed exceptions.
     * @param string $message
     * @param int $code
     * @param \Exception|null $previous
     */
    public function __construct($message = "", $code = self::CODE_UNKNOWN, RawException $previous = null)
    {
        if(self::$holdYourHorses) {
            // In this block we might put some dummy variables with useful values...
            // like the requested URI or the amount of memory currently in use
            if(function_exists('xdebug_break')) {
                xdebug_break();
            }
        }

        $this->baseConstructorCalled = true;
        parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);
    }

    /**
     * This assertion should be called by the main exception handler if the application is NOT running in production.
     * @throws \LogicException
     */
    public function assertConstructionChain()
    {
        if(!$this->baseConstructorCalled) {
            $nastyBoy = get_class($this);
            throw new LogicException("Please ensure that the constructor chain of $nastyBoy is implemented properly!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You right simple solution, but sometimes you do not want to have a centralized exception handling, sometimes you need them in special modules and you want to keep them in one area of the code to handle them there. But right i could define/extend different Excpetions. One the bubbles up to the centralized hadnling and other that do not bubble up. I should have come to the same idea by my own:-) hey brain where are you?

Comment: @Gizzmo Check out my edit sir. Btw, I'm in the beloved banana country (aka Brazil)...

Comment: Nice code thx! Damn i am i a country where now it's fu... cold;-)